# Running ROS in docker container and echo/pub from another docker container within same docker network (non-host network)

Tags: docker, ros, docker-container, docker-network

I am working on running ROS in one docker container and trying to rosnode list to check the information from another container which both of them are under same customize docker network (non host).

From the docker side, I am pretty sure that two of the containers could talk with each other because I've tried to `ping container1` from container2 without loss any packet.

The container1 IP is `172.22.0.2` and the container2 IP is `172.22.0.3`

I've setup the config of both of container as following:

container1 `export ROS_IP=172.22.0.2 export ROS_MASTER_URL=http://172.22.0.2:11311/`

container2 `export ROS_IP=172.22.0.3 export ROS_MASTER_URL=http://172.22.0.2:11311/`

After that, I start to run `roscore` on container1 and input command `rosnode list` on container2, however the container2 showing error message: `Unable to communicate with master!`

It seems like even I setup ros master url for both of the container, I am still not able to share the same roscore between containers.

Is there anything might be missing or something I did is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environmental variable you need is `ROS_MASTER_URI` not `ROS_MASTER_URL`. Set the former to the master IP.

Comment: I think that is the most silly thing I did for my entire life. Thanks for correct me and it works fine now